# Spring 14 debug log verbosity

Tags: spring14

OK, my sandboxes just got upgraded to Spring 14; I run a test, using an existing testmethod, using the same debug log levels I used in Winter 14. But now, I get hyper (and useless) verbosity of debug output (note apex code: INFO level)

```
27.0 APEX_CODE,INFO;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
11:56:56.494 (12494752000)|EXECUTION_STARTED
11:56:56.494 (12494809000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|  [EXTERNAL]|01pd0000002LkyS|Test_AccountControllerExtension00.testConstructor
11:56:56.495 (12495397000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
11:56:56.495 (12495525000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
11:56:56.495 (12495592000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[16]
11:56:56.495 (12495597000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[17]
11:56:56.546 (12546548000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
11:56:56.546 (12546583000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
11:56:56.546 (12546587000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[114]
11:56:56.546 (12546613000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[117]
11:56:56.546 (12546974000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[321]
11:56:56.546 (12546981000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[322]
11:56:56.569 (12569665000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
11:56:56.569 (12569700000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
11:56:56.569 (12569704000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[50]
11:56:56.569 (12569749000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[53]
11:56:56.569 (12569816000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[54]
11:56:56.569 (12569859000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[55]
11:56:56.570 (12570070000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[56]
11:56:56.570 (12570124000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[57]
11:56:56.570 (12570169000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[63]
11:56:56.570 (12570175000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[63]
```

and on and on for 1.5 M bytes of debug log. I don't want a log of every statement executed.

I never used to get these debug outputs - statement-by-statement.

STATEMENT_EXECUTE is only supposed to appear at Apex Code Log Level FINER or FINEST; certainly not at INFO

Problem occurs when running test from setup | develop | apex test execution as well as from eclipse IDE; Developer Console is even worse as it doesn't honor debug level setting (although I can filter after-the-fact).  Here is a Developer Console log:

[image: Developer Console log]

> Update 1445h Pacific
>       Followed workaround here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0DsAAK for semi-related Winter 14 issue. I deleted all my TraceFlags; this fixed the problem for Eclipse IDE (filters now work as expected) but had no effect on debug logs when I ran Setup | Develop | Apex test Execution and inspected results on Setup | Monitoring | Debug Logs -- still get every statement and debug log sizes are huge.
>
> Note that if you specify in Developer Console via Change Log Levels a general logging level you will get one row for yourself and if you create a debug log monitoring yourself as a user via Setup | Monitoring | Debug Logs, you will see a second row for yourself in Developer Console. Each row corresponds to a TraceFlag row in the metadata. It is not obvious to you which row in the Developer Console popup of Debug Log levels is the one used by tests run within Developer Console and which row is the one used by tests run in the Force.com User Interface. You can see an example in the screen shot
>
> Update at 1745h Pacific. I can't explain it. I changed my DC log levels to Apex code: INFO, Validation: ERROR, Workflow: ERROR, Profiling: ERROR and System: WARN
>   ; others at defaults and now the debug log displays as expected when run from DC. If I run the test from Setup | Develop | Apex Test Execution, it ignores whatever debug log settings I established in Setup | Monitor | Debug Logs and executes the test using the debug log levels established by DC.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: I had once similar issue with my debug, I am not sure if it was just temporary issue.... But in my case it helped when I deleted myself from debug in Salesfroce(and all logs) and just checked logs in console

Comment: Yesterday in several orgs I was not able to set up the debug levels and in even was not able to see any exception...Sometimes we needed to delete de debug user and re-create it.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the monitored user as my first amelioration attempt and it had no effect. I would agree with @ Birthus and @ Carolina that deleting the monitored user immediately after an SFDC new release seems 'best practice'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debug log verbosity issue in Spring 14 sandboxes has disappeared. I can no longer reproduce the issue; debug log settings in both **DC** and **Setup | Monitoring | Debug Logs** now work as expected.  While some on SFSE may feel the OP was 'user error', you can see from the top of the log trace in the OP that APEX_Code was INFO but actual logging was as if it were APEX_CODE: FINER.

In discussion with SFDC Support, they indicated that there was a similar case opened with 'too verbose' debug logs and it was 'fixed on a priority basis'.

I hesitate to get reputation points for answering my own question when I just let time pass, so the SFSE moderator can remove such points with no complaint by me.

Some additional information for the perplexed:

1. Although the documentation states that you setup logs in Setup | Monitor | Debug Logs for any given user X, if there is no log monitoring setup for yourself, you can still get a log in DC by simply running as yourself some test class.
2. Similarly, you can have debug log settings established in DC as shown in the picture even if no user is being monitored.
3. When you run your testclass in DC, if both #1 and #2 apply, you may or may not see the logs appear in DC (I was using Firefox); if they don't appear, close and re-open DC.
4. When you run your testclass in DC, if both #1 and #2 apply, whatever debug log levels you have set in DC are ignored and the default log levels are used (e.g. APEX_CODE, DEBUG)

[image]

The interrelationship between the DC **Change Debug Log Levels** dialog and the Force.com **Setup | Monitoring | Debug Logs** is shown here:

[image]

And, I think this was introduced in Spring 14 - the log list pane will spuriously record FATAL exceptions, even if caught and handled in your code as shown in the following screen shot. I can live with this as I pay attention to the green checks, not the Status column. Note all green checks to the left - entire test class passed.
[image]

Comment: Nice piece of research. Debug logs have been one of the most unstable and unpredictable features in Force.com. It sounds like some work has been put into improving it. I look forward to seeing the results for myself.

Comment: @kibitzer - I'm glad I'm not the only one who finds debug logs 'capricious'.  When one is debugging, one doesn't want to debug the debugging process!

Answer (score 1):

You can set your log levels lower.  You're on FINEST by default, and you can eliminate STATEMENT_EXECUTE by dropping to FINE or lower.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_debugging_system_log_console.htm

Comment: my log level is APEX_CODE: INFO; not FINEST